# My first oft comes first

Tags: riddle, word

My first oft comes first, My second can fly, My third is deep, and some pronounce my last differently to others.

Hint:

> I have more between the third and last

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are

> **Alphabets**

First comes first

> Letter **A** comes *first*

Second can fly

> **B** -> *Bee* -> *Can fly*

Third is deep

> **C** -> *Sea* -> *Is deep*

Last is pronounced differently

> **Z** -> *Zed* -> *Zee*

Hint

> More in between third and last -> *D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y*

Comment: That was quick!

Comment: @Raeles Nice start! I would advice holding the hints for a while if they are a give away. :)

Comment: $(+1)$ You included *all* that is in between in your hint explanation :)